# Lock writing a Property

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

In my class I have this property :

```
public List<MyObject> mCollection { get; set; }
```

This collection is used in some different threads.

What I would like to do it's to allow writing this property only when all threads have finished reading `mCollection`.

Something like taking and release a token, and to allow writing only when all token are released. Is there something like that in the framework ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve that. To keep it simple, make your readers cooperate by synchronizing with each other.

- Let readers take a read lock with `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Have the writer take a write lock.
- Make readers signal a `CountdownEvent`. Make the writer wait on it.
- Make all readers and writers `SignalAndWait` a `Barrier` so that the writer proceeds only when everyone is done.

Pick what matches your scenario.

Comment: while this answers what asked, I strongly believe that the correct approach would be to use structures suitable for multi-threaded applications instead of a very complex locking solutions.

Comment: @SKleanthous you might be right but for this question a) I answer what was is requested and b) it is unclear what those structures would be because it is hard to guess what the usage of that object and list look like. Also, he might require sequencing side-effects like web-service calls (his texts suggest he really wants to wait). We can't just unblock readers by using immutable structures. Too much guessing here.

Comment: It is true that immutable collections are not without their requirements, but all of the "problems" introduced could be better minimized with the use of good design and (if needed) other frameworks like Dataflow to chain up events.

Comment: I would also like to add that using locks in calling code can be extremely error prone, as it depends on the calling methods to coordinate. Future implementors may miss this and introduce bugs.

Answer (score 0):

While there are some constructs that can help like [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx), I strongly believe that there are far better approaches to your problem. This could be like using [ImmutableList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) instead of List and changing your calling code to use that.

The use of a locking mechanism in your scenario, has to be implemented by the callers and the ones who have access to your property. Since this is public, you do not have any means to enforce callers to submit to a locking mechanism, other than retrieving the list, wrapped in an IDisposable that will release the lock on dispose (it is a bit more complex that this as you have to lock before getting an IEnumerator). Again however, I believe that a restructuring of your source code to use proven constructs is a better solution.

If you need to chain events or processors, I would strongly suggest that you use TPL Dataflow. This will free you from the problems faced when one thread waits for something to become available, and will also result in significantly better designed and more easily maintainable code.